# How to implement a "Twitter Feed Pattern" with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm dealing with a design pattern here.
I'm creating an App where you have followers and followings. Similar to Twitter, Instagram, x-social-network.

Basically, when an user opens the "Home" view, I need to call a Firebase Function that should get the followers' activity feed (like twitter, insta, etc) from a Firestore DB.

I thought about doing something like this:

For this example, let suppose that user `A` follows the users `B`

1. Every time user `B` does something that should be included in the feed of `A`, I'll add a new object in `B.feed`. Something like:

`B.feed['timestampId'] = { eventType: 'new-tweet', photoId: 123123};`

2. When the user `A` opens the Home view, I call the "getFeed" Firebase Function (this step is not the important one).
3. The "getFeed" Firebase Function is going to get the users that `A` is following.
4. Then, for each `A.following` user (in this case it's only `B`), I'll get the `X.feed` object. In this case: the `B.feed`, and I'll return it to the App.

What is the problem here?
If `A` is following more than 1 user (let's say, `B`, and `C`), the common sense says that I should get the `.feed` of user `B` and `C`.
In the old way, with SQL, I'll do something like "SELECT FEED WHERE user_id IN ('B', 'C')". But, as you may know, there are no `OR` in Firestore calls.

Meaning, I can not do:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('id', '=', 'B')
  .where('id', '=', 'C')
  .get()
```

So, what I actually should do, is call `n` times that query, where `n` is the number of users that `A` is following.

```
admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('id', '=', 'B')
  .get()

admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('id', '=', 'C')
  .get()
```

Wait for all those promises, and then return the `.feed` of all those calls.

It feels like... I don't know... Ugly (in all the senses that you may imagine).

Do you guys have a better idea about how to implement something like this?